# Layout not updating

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

I opened a new android project with eclipse.
edited the layout (in my case main.xml).
everything was fine. After I saved my project and reopened it, I wanted to edit the layout to add some buttons.
now when I run the app on the AVD, the layout looks like it was before editing it.
a deleted the `main.xml` all together and ran it on the AVD. To my surprise it loaded fine with the old layout.
Whats going on??

Here is my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".BidirectionalAndroidTCPClientActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/connect"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="connect" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/tog1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="toggle1"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="clearText"
        android:text="Clear Log1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onQuit"
        android:text="Exit" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/console" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textlog"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh Eclipse project by clicking on project with right mouse button, and than refresh. Also try to clean and build project.

Answer (score 0):

Clean and build and you will be fine.

Directions:
Projects -> Clean. Then check the project and click OK.
Let me know if this fixes you issue.